# InstallShield LE doesn't install MS Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)

Tags: visual-c++, installshield, windows-7-x64, redistributable

I'm using InstallShield Limited Edition to create installer (setup.exe) for my project. My project requires Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86), and I want include this redist into my setup.exe. I do it in Redistributables view in my InstallShield project - just selecting Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) as InstallShield Prerequisite component and setting 'Extract From Setup.exe' property for it.

I decided to test my setup.exe on XP box and Win7 box. For this purpose I deleted Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable from these boxes (via Control Panel->Uninstall program) and tried to install my app. My expected result is - c++ redist will be installed before my project installation.

But I have different results: I have no problem when installing it on XP box: it installed c++ redist first and my app then. Works as it should be!
But when I launched setup.exe on Win7 box it didn't install c++ redist - it only installed my app. Can anyone explain this?

Btw, Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86) had size ~11 mb and version 10.0.40219 on my Win7 box before I uninstalled it. Now I downloaded it from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555, installed **manually** and... I see that now it has version 10.0.30319 and size only ~918 kb. So, I wonder again, what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This may be related to the operatingsystemconditions configuration in the Installshield pre-requisite file Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86).prq located in the Installshield SetupPrerequisites directory.

The operatingsystemconditions section specifies which versions of Windows, including service packs, 32/64 bits, the redistributable file should be installed on.

See http://daniellang.net/installshield-and-microsoft-visual-c-2010-redistributables/ for some more details.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed the SP1 redist, but there is an updated version with a MFC security update.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2565063